# Send log to a specific Graylog Index via Nxlog configuration

Tags: graylog2, nxlog

I am currently using nxlog to send the server logs to a graylog2 server and all the messages are going to the default index in Graylog. I am trying to send the messages to a particular index which should be configurable from the nxlog conf file.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot achieve this via Nxlog configuration. This problem can be solved by using Streams functionality provided by Graylog http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/streams.html . We can create a stream with a particular rule to figure out the input source and then redirect the logs to a particular index which is configured when we are creating a stream.